# Updating incorrect ecommerce data in GA4 Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We have had some e-commerce purchase data in GA4 over reported due to an error in the our system, and we need to adjust this in GA4 so it reflects correctly.

What is the best way to adjust this?

We have tried to adjust by using the **Data Import ->Offline event data** function via a CSV. However when we upload the CSV we get a 500 internal error from google, no reason given by google for the failure.

As far s we can tell the CSV we're uploading follows their template correctly.

[image]

- Is this the correct/best way to adjust incorrect sales data in google?
- Is there a better way to do it?
- Any insights on what might be causing the 500 error on offline data import if this is the correct approach.

May thanks in advance.